# Randomly Split DataFrame by Unique Values in One Column

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a pyspark DataFrame like the following:

```
+--------+--------+-----------+
| col1   |  col2  |  groupId  |
+--------+--------+-----------+
| val11  | val21  |   0       |
| val12  | val22  |   1       |
| val13  | val23  |   2       |
| val14  | val24  |   0       |
| val15  | val25  |   1       |
| val16  | val26  |   1       |
+--------+--------+-----------+
```

Each row has a `groupId` and multiple rows can have the same `groupId`.

I want to randomly split this data into two datasets. But all the data having a particular `groupId` must be in one of the splits.

This means that if `d1.groupId = d2.groupId`, then `d1` and `d2` are in the same split.

For example:

```
# Split 1:

+--------+--------+-----------+
| col1   |  col2  |  groupId  |
+--------+--------+-----------+
| val11  | val21  |   0       |
| val13  | val23  |   2       |
| val14  | val24  |   0       |
+--------+--------+-----------+

# Split 2:
+--------+--------+-----------+
| col1   |  col2  |  groupId  |
+--------+--------+-----------+
| val12  | val22  |   1       |
| val15  | val25  |   1       |
| val16  | val26  |   1       |
+--------+--------+-----------+
```

What is the good way to do it on PySpark? Can I use the `randomSplit` method somehow?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `randomSplit` to split just the distinct `groupId`s, and then use the results to split the source DataFrame using `join`.

For example:

```python
split1, split2 = df.select("groupId").distinct().randomSplit(weights=[0.5, 0.5], seed=0)
split1.show()
#+-------+
#|groupId|
#+-------+
#|      1|
#+-------+

split2.show()
#+-------+
#|groupId|
#+-------+
#|      0|
#|      2|
#+-------+
```

Now join these back to the original DataFrame:

```python
df1 = df.join(split1, on="groupId", how="inner")
df2 = df.join(split2, on="groupId", how="inner")

df1.show()
3+-------+-----+-----+
#|groupId| col1| col2|
#+-------+-----+-----+
#|      1|val12|val22|
#|      1|val15|val25|
#|      1|val16|val26|
#+-------+-----+-----+

df2.show()
#+-------+-----+-----+
#|groupId| col1| col2|
#+-------+-----+-----+
#|      0|val11|val21|
#|      0|val14|val24|
#|      2|val13|val23|
#+-------+-----+-----+
```